# Network architecture to predict zero-inflated output

Tags: neural-networks, zero-inflation

I have a dataset of debt collections and I am trying to predict how much each person paid. The paid amounts are greatly zero-inflated.

In the past I have built a two-stage model predicting the probability of payment followed by the payment amount. It seems that a neural network would be a good choice to learn both models at the same time.

However, when it comes to activation and loss functions for the final output layer predicting payment amount I am stuck. I have tried a relu activation and an mse loss but it doesn't converge.

What network architecture could be used to predict a heavily zero-inflated outcome?

[image]

Comment: Not enough reputation for comment, so just adding an answer. Try taking the log(1+x) of your output variable you have plotted, this should create a much more gaussian like target, which should help things.

Comment: @Sridhar Thank you for the interesting idea.  Unfortunately, that won't work: the data will still be (clearly) bimodal.